# Mobile app clicks decline after February 6th

Tags: mobile, click, traffic, facebook-insights

On our app insights we've noticed a rapid decline in the traffic that comes from mobile devices (insights > traffic > mobile) straight after the last February 6th breaking changes. Are there more developers here who suffered similar declines lately?
Unfortunately for us this happened 2 days before launching some improved and responsive screens especially for our iPhone users..

Answer (score 0):

Your insight problem probably relates to the recent Facebook insight bug that has also impacted mobile devices such as you are seeing already.  The mobile issue is covered in more detail over on [TechCrunch](http://techcrunch.com/2013/02/22/facebook-insights-bugs/).  You can read the [official Facebook](http://www.facebook-studio.com/news/item/important-update-to-page-insights-reporting) post but doesn't cover the mobile insight issue yet...

Hope that helps.